# SharePoint Designer Creates Duplicate Tasks

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that will create a task when a new list item is created. This task is then workflowed to users depending on which group they are a member of.

The problem i have is sometime i have to select multiple groups and then if a user is in both groups then they get 2 of the same tasks created.

Is there a way to stop the duplicate tasks being created?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can check the groups for the existence of the same user across the groups if multiple groups are selected and that way you can pare down the duplicate tasks.  Been some time since I've used SharePoint designer but you should be able to check whether a user is in a group or not.

Comment: That for the response. I'm not even sure where i would look for that, i've had a look through SP designer and can't see any option for what you're talking about.